# How to send input when calling Matlab script from python?

Tags: python, matlab, tkinter

I have a python Tkinter code which is linked with Matlab. I am calling the Matlab script by importing matlab.engine . The python code when it runs uses the output of Matlab code. I want to decide which image to be read in Matlab from python. I want to give that image address as an input in python code so that when Matlab code runs, it takes that input and reads it through imread(). Can somebody please help me how can I do that?

This is the part of the code which is used to call Matlab script
I tried to send 'xys' as an input but it gives the error.

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
xys="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\tkinter_codes\\floorplans\\ROBIN\\Dataset_3roomsmall\\Cat1_1.jpg"
eng.boundingbox_Aroundrooms(nargout=0)
```

Comment: Just convert your MATLAB script to a MATLAB function that takes the name as an input argument. Also what error do you get?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: Attempt to execute SCRIPT boundingbox_Aroundrooms as a function: This is the error I got. Could you please tell me How can I convert the script to a function?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to write your data in a file with a specific format and then load it again in the other program. However, it gets tricky if you want to run both apps simultaneously. I had this issue a while ago but my case was very simple and I could get it done this way.